# iBeacon background monitoring stops working

Tags: ios, ios9, core-location, ibeacon

I have an app that monitors iBeacons entry/exit events. When it receives an event it forwards the event off to a server. The app continues to work (e.g., the server continues to receive updates) after the user minimizes and/or force closes it (so it works correctly in the background).

However, after a phone has been away from any iBeacons for a sufficient amount of time (e.g., overnight) and is brought near iBeacons again, the app stops receiving enter/exit updates until the user opens it up again (brings it into the foreground). If the user minimizes/closes the app at that point, updates continue to work correctly in the background.

Is anything that I need to do to allow long running monitoring updates in the background? After a while does iOS stop background monitoring?

*Note: I am running iOS 9.3.1*

Comment: did you ask the user for this: Use of this service requires “Always” authorization from the user.

Comment: Yes, I am using "Always" authorization. I believe this is working correctly as I continue to observe updates hours after the user minimize / force close the app.

Answer (score 3):

**iOS Apps are supposed to be able to detect beacons indefinitely in the background** when they have been granted "always" location access.

This is the second report I have heard like this, so I wonder if it is a bug or a change in a new iOS version.  Reporting your iOS version would be helpful.

One possibility: **the network calls may be being blocked and not the beacon detections**.  You could test this hypothesis by adding NSLog statements to :

1. Log on beacon detection
2. Log on successful and unsuccessful connection to the server.

Once you add the above, reproduce the issue where you don't see events on your server.  Then connect your phone to XCode and go to Devices, and look at the recent NSLog output to see:

1. Is there a line indicating the beacon was detected?
2. Was the server connection successful or not?

If you find it is the network connection that is failing, you may be able to correct the situation by requesting additional background network permissions.

**EDIT:** One other thing you might try when a detection is not made is launching a different beacon scanner app in the foreground like [Locate](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-beacon/id738709014?mt=8).  This will force an OS bluetooth scan and it might kick off your app's detection.  If this works, it would tell you that bluetooth scanning had been suspended across the phone.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll give this a shot. One thing that makes me skeptical that it's a network issue is that I don't even see the suggested app icon appear on the lock screen when it stops working. My understanding is that if an app is detects beacons that it is monitoring for, iOS will display that apps icon on the bottom left of the lock screen.

Comment: Agreed that you should be suspicious since you don't see the icon.  See my   edit on my question for one other suggestion.  Also, please do post your iOS version.

Comment: I tried launching a different beacon scanner app - we're using Estimote beacons, so I launched the Estimote scanner app. It was able to see the beacon(s) in the Estimote app, however, my app did not wake up, and continued to not receive any beacon updates until I launched it again. I was optimistic that this might work, but unfortunately it did not.

Comment: I can confirm there are issues on latest iOS Versions (iOS 9.3) or higher. Location monitoring for iBeacons works for some days and then suddenly stop. Makes this feature at the moment almost useless.